# home network, PC sharing to router, plus VPN questions

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, home-networking, connection-sharing

This is what I am trying to do:

Share cable internet from my PC to a router while using VPN, with everything being on the network.

Here is what I have done:

- Cable internet modem is connected to Ethernet card 1 on the PC.
- Then I connect to the VPN.  I then share the virtual adapter from the VPN via Windows ICS to my second Ethernet card (#2).
- The second Ethernet card is connect to my router LAN port (not WAN).
- Router DHCP and wan settings are turned off (since ICS has own NAT, etc.).

So internet does work over my router and to the devices connected to it.  All of my connected devices seem to be connected to the VPN.  However, all of my IP address are on different subnets / gateways than the PC.

Is there any way I can make both Ethernet cards and the router appear on the same network? For example, I can't connect to my router admin page in the current configuration from my PC which is sharing the internet connection.

I attached a diagram of how it is set up so far:

[image: network diagram]

I found similar questions asked on this site,
but I am out of luck trying solutions.

What do I need to do to get everything on the same network? Another example,so if a printer is shared, it can be seen by devices connected to the router and also the host PC.

Comment: Anyone want to take a guess?  Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the point of doing this? All you are doing is adding complexity to the network for no stated benefit... Why don't you just setup the router as a VPN client?

Comment: Routers have slower processing speed.  I can get 100mbps connection on my pc connected to vpn verses the 20mbps via a router.